# OpenGL Lighting for uniform illumination

Tags: opengl, 3d

Have a look at the following 2 images -

[image]

[image]

The 2 images are of the same model at different angles. It is made of multiple cylinders stacked on top of each other. As you can see there is something funny with the lighting. One side of all cylinders is dark in the first image. When the same model is rotated, the other end of all the cylinders becomes dark. The explanation is pretty clear. The normals get aligned in the direction of light to light up one side. I want both sides to be equally well lit and not compromise on the 3d look and feel of the cylinder. How should I set up the lighting?

I am using Smooth Shading.

Comment: You don't give us any clue to find out what happens. Did you created those by hand? It's not the lighting, it's the cilinders: they have the normals turned... did you created them?

Comment: @darkgaze I created the cylinders. What do you mean by normals turned ? I am using OpenSceneGraph library. It is capable of computing normals by itself. I tested using the library function and my own normal generation algorithm and I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what the problem is without more information.

What I think is happening is that the cylinders were created with smooth shading normals. This is visually pleasing but it can create problems like this one when the poly count is low.

[image: types of shading]
<sub>(source: [k-3D.org](http://www.k-3D.org/k3d_wiki/images/c/ce/Normals.png))</sub>

In this image, the first cylinder from the left has flat shading and the middle one has smooth shading. As you can see in this example, the smooth shaded one also has problems with too little light on one side. The reason is that, with smooth shading, the normals on the edge of the cylinder are an average of the normals from the side and the normals from the top, and that can cause lighting problems. See this diagram:

[image: diagram]

The yellow arrow is the light direction, the red is the smooth normal and the greens are the flat normals. See how the angle between the smooth normal and the light is around 90º so it will get no light.

The solution is to set the normals as smooth, but detach the top and bottom faces from the side. This way, the circular edge won't get smoothed but the side will. The result is the third cylinder on the first image.

If you cannot achieve that with your software, an easy solution is to add a bevel around the edges like this:

[image: bevel]

The bevel can be as small as you want and it will achieve the effect you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome answer. Very well explained. Works very well. Thanks.